# How to connect android app to google cloud storage via JSON API

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-storage

I have problem with connect my Android App to Google Cloud Storage.
I want to connect via JSON API, i can't use google authorization for this.

I generated API key. In the Internet I found, that I should do this on manifest .xml:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="??????"
            android:value="MY_API_KEY" />
```

but I don't know, what I should put on:

```
android:name="??????"
```

Can You help me?

Comment: Why don't you edit your title to reflect the actual problem you want a solution to?

Comment: Do you want the app to authenticate as the user or as an account associated with your application?

Comment: this option: account associated with your application

Answer (score 1):

`"Meta-data contains a name-value pair for an item of additional, arbitrary data that can be supplied to the parent component"

A meta-data is made up of the following:

`Android:name:`
A unique name for the item. To ensure that the name is unique, use a Java-style naming convention — for example, "com.example.project.activity.fred".

`android:resource:`
A reference to a resource. The ID of the resource is the value assigned to the item. The ID can be retrieved from the meta-data Bundle by the Bundle.getInt() method.

`Android:value:`
The value assigned to the item. The data types that can be assigned as values and the Bundle methods that components use to retrieve those values are listed in the following table:
 [source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html).

You are supposed to use a unique name for the API-KEY as it is in your app.Take a look at these two examples:

```
<meta-data 
   android:name="my_api_key" 
   android:value="mykey123" /> 

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

In the second example, `@integer/google_play_services_version"` gets the value from `string.xml`.

Simply put,  `name` expects the name of the stuff you intend to use in the meta-data and `value` expects the value of that stuff.

Read [this](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/10/08/using-meta-data-in-an-androidmanifest/) good explanation of how to use the `Meta-data` in the manifest.

Comment: I do this, but it's still don't work.
Maybe is another way to authorize my app to google cloud storage? please help me

Comment: I haven't any error message.
I try this on device.

I call function:
` public void getlist(View view) throws IOException {
Storage.Objects.List listObjects = storage.objects().list("mybucket");
Objects objects;
do {
  objects = listObjects.execute();
  for (StorageObject object : objects.getItems()) {
    // Do things!
  }
  listObjects.setPageToken(objects.getNextPageToken());
} while (null != objects.getNextPageToken());
    }`

Comment: So what is the problem? If it's not working then there has to be an error message.Check your console.